# Maximum length of messages in MQ and SIB Queue(s)

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-7, websphere-8

From the docs, I understand that WebSphere MQ can support messages up to size 100 MB. What is the size limit for the SIBus queues in WAS? Can it also support messages up to 100 MB?

Is there a limit on the file sizes that can be handled by the RFHUtil tool?

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the WAS Infocenter [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmj_jmsp_sibvmq.html), SIBus is designed for messages up to 40MB on 32-bit systems.

RFHUtil should handle messages up to the max size allowed.  However, be aware that message properties may *or may not* count towards that size, depending on tuning.  The Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01) should also handle messages of any allowable size.